# fadeOut (on an li) stops working after using addClass on div that wraps the ul

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a "slider". I have a main ul for the main content (e.g., images), as well as a second ul for a thumbnail carousel. Click a thumb (or a prev / next) and I transitions from the current li (read index) to the clicked li using this line:

```
cacheMainImagesList.siblings('li').eq(currentIndex).fadeOut(opts.imageOutDuration, function(){cacheMainImagesList.eq(displayThisIndex).fadeIn(opts.imageInDuration)});
```

I'm not acting on the images themselves because I'm shooting for a content slider and not just an image slider. That said, I'm wanting to have a full screen mode. Click a button and the images will fill the screen.

To do the full-screen, I'm adding a class to the outer most wrapper. That class is defined as position: fixed, left:0, top:0. (Note: I don't think this detail matters but what the heck.) The leap to full screen work. It's basically the same uls just wrapped up and CSS'ed slightly different.

However, the line of code above stops working. I'm not getting an error. Specifically, the fadeOut simply stops working. The fadeIn works but for some reason the fadeOut doesn't. In short, the slides stop "sliding", then just pile up. I can go forward in the index, 2, 3, 4, etc. But when I try to go back the currentIndex never does the fadeOut.

Finally, I tried to force it with a hide() but then there's a "flash" of sorts. I also don't want the instant effect of hide. Even if it's a super fast fade, that's still more pleasing.

Anyone have any clues? Obviously, I do not. Thanks.

Perhaps this will help: jsfiddle.net/chiefalchemist/UvpGN/5 Please see comment below about this working. That is, it doesn't reproduce the broke fadeOut.

Let me break it down to its most basic level...The fadeOut and fadeIn are operating on on the same selector / object in the same line of code. It's a matter of two different indexs being changed. Why does fadeout not work but fadeIn does? That's why I'm stumped.

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow.  If you could reduce your problem to its simplest form in a jsFiddle, you would probably find more people able to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 Here ya go. http://jsfiddle.net/chiefalchemist/UvpGN/5/ The thing is, this works as expext. Obviously / perhaps I've got a hole somewhere else in my plugin code. But I've been up and down it and am just looking for some good guess on what would create the bug described. Why would fadeOut not work but also not throw an error? Or better still, why would fadeOut not work but the faceIn tied to its complete work? In works but not Out? Help.

Comment: Try breaking this down: a) console.log() each part, cacheMainImagesList, then cacheMainImageList.siblings('li'), then the next one. It's quite possible one of the selectors is different to what you expect after the change.

Comment: Not the problem, but this is inefficient: `$(document).find('#fullscreen');`.  `$("#fullscreen")` is much cleaner and faster.  For some reason you're using `$(document).find()` everywhere rather than just use a straight selector.  That's just wasteful.

Comment: Here's a much cleaned up version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/g9vd5/.  I can' reproduce your problem so not sure how to debug/troubleshoot something I can't see.  `fadeOut()` will not appear to work when the object it addresses is not visible or when the selector it's called on results in an empty jQuery object.  Neither of those conditions is a jQuery error so no errors are thrown.

Comment: @jfriend00 - The $(document). was just a jsfiddle quick n dirty. My mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. I don't think that's my problem with the fadeOut. Ya think? I understand what you're saying about the fadeOut(). I hear ya. However, the fadeIn *is* working on the very same selector / object. And that's where I get lost. I think it has something to do with the display property and how it get interpreted differently for some reason. The object is there, it's the property that's not changing. The question is why isn't it? If anything comes to mind let me know. Or I can send ya a zip.

Comment: That's where you're wrong.  It's not the same selector for `fadeOut()` as for `fadeIn()` and that's probably where the goof is.  Something is probably getting messed up with `currentIndex` or `newIn`, but without some way to make it happen, we can't help other than guess.

Comment: Both are doing a Fade to a different index within: cacheMainImagesList. I've since removed the .siblings('li') for the fadeOut and everything remains the same. Same "bug". So if the FadeIn is to follow the FadeOut and that work corrertly not in fullscreen (which is just a class added to a wrapper div) why / how does FadeIn continue to work but FadeOut does not? That doesn't make since to me. Step 1 is broken but Step 2 - which follows Step 1 (duh? :)) - works are expected. I might be wrong but this code is totalled effed ;)

Comment: @jfriend00 - Ok, I've pinned it down to this line of CSS: .ezis-status-fullscreen .ezis-main-slides img.ezis-display-full {position:fixed; top:0; left:0;width:100%;z-index:350} -fullscreen is the outer wrapper of everything; -main-slides wrap the ul with the image in it; the img is the image; -display-full is an "flag" class that says "use this image for this fullscreen mode". the "trick" for the this line of CSS came from: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ So why would this screw up fadeOut? And not the fadeIn? Anything?

Comment: All I can say is that you're mixing a lot of stuff that could easily have browser bugs or cross-browser compatibility issues.  You're mixing: parent with `position: fixed`, parent with `z-index: 350`, child element, partial opacity, hiding and showing.  Since you cannot reproduce the problem in a simpler jsFiddle, the issue is in your complexity so the answer is likely in simplifying the CSS and not trying to use so many CSS tricks.

Comment: I agree that it does not make sense that a fadeIn would work and a fadeOut would not, but we've already established that the browser is confused by your complexity.  If you can show a page that reproduces the problem, we might be able to help further - otherwise all we can do is continue to make guesses.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Thanks again for your help. I agree, the browser doesn't like what it's seeing. Duh? :) But what a fuster cluck, eh? What I'm gonna do it just "hardcode" (on the fly) the width into the image (as based on the browser width) and not rely on the CSS for the resizing. It's the CSS that's the problem so I gotta ditch it. Who knew?

Comment: @jfriend00 - check it out, I've made some progress - I think. Upon further consideration I realized the fadeOut was on the li. But the full-screen positioning was fixed to be "outside" (on top of, so to speak) the li. i did a quick change to also change the positioning of the li and the fade works. the location isn't quite right but I'll figure that out. hopefully what i just said made sense. if not let me know and i'll try to explain again. interesting, yes?