# fadeOut "disabled" by a seemingly benign line of CSS (jquery bug?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a follow up to:

[fadeOut (on an li) stops working after using addClass on div that wraps the ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438556/fadeout-on-an-li-stops-working-after-using-addclass-on-div-that-wraps-the-ul)

Now that I've scoped it down to a single line of CSS it seems like a good spot to reask the (now) correct question.

This is the line of CSS:

```
.status-fullscreen .main-slides img.display-full {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    z-index:350
}
```

(btw, this "trick" comes from: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ so it's seems pretty legit.)

Pseudo code it applies to:

```
<div .status-fullscreen>
  <div .main-slides>
  <ul>
    <li><img .display-full /></li>
    <li><img .display-full /></li>
    <li><img .display-full /></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the line of CSS is in play and I'm working the .go(index) of the list, fadeOut() stops working as expected. That is, it doesn't work at all. fadeIn works tho' the duration seems to be off. Remove the line and all is well.

What gives?

I'm sure there's another way to produce fullscreen image. NBD. But it would be nice / helpful to understand what cause fadeOut to be eff'ed by what's in this line of CSS. Maybe it's not a bug but it does seem pretty damn odd, yes?

Comment: you mean, `class="status-fullscreen"` and `class="main-slides"` and `class="display-full"`, just so we're clear here, right?

Comment: Rather than referring to another question could you show the line of JS that includes your `.fadeOut()`? Also, given that your CSS includes five different settings have you tried removing them one at a time to see if it's a particular one that causes the problem?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - Yup. It was just pseudo code to save keystrokes.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Yes, I've done that. Thx. My point is, what in that single line of CSS is in any way related to Fade? I've scoped the problem. I'll find a work around. In the meantime, I'm just putting this bug (?) out there as a WTF. Fair enough? That said, if I remove any of the settings it'll wonk the full screen effect so doing so (aside from the z-index) probably isn't an option. Kinda all or nothing. Ya dig? Thx again.

Comment: Well `.fadeOut()` works by changing the `opacity`, and I have in the past noticed some weird interaction between `opacity` and `z-index` with overlapping elements. But sorry, I don't have an actual answer for you.

Comment: @nnnnnn Re: z-index. Will do, thanks. I'll play around with that. In a way that's kinda the issue. One photo is layering up on top of the previous. Interesting. Re: "don't have an actual answer" Well, yeah. I know that feeling :) Still kinda feels like a bug to me, else there would be / should be a pretty clear answer, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Instead of just using the single line on the image to make it full screen, I also used fixed and height on the

and on out to the wrapper (if that makes sense.). In short, in make layer on top consistently defined (I guess) the code stopped confusing jq.